# Is there a way to specify .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None) as a decorator to my entity?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following class. I was using a mapping file but I would not like to decorate the class with the different options. I already have in my mapping file:

```
.HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

How can I set this or set another option of DatabaseGeneratedOption by decorating the class? I looked at the Intellisense options but can't find one for this all I can find is `[DatabaseGenerated()]` and I am not sure if that's correct or how to set that option:

```
[DatabaseGenerated()]

public class ContentType : Entity
{
    public ContentType()
    {
        this.Contents = new List<Content>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int ContentTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Content> Contents { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DatabaseGenerated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is Property and Field specific attribute. You can't add it to a class, only specific properties or fields.